# XSLT : Sum based on attributes values

Tags: xml, xslt, sum, attributes

I have this document I want to transform to a HTLM doc, using XSLT. I want to sum up the prices by city, meaning I would have the following output :

```
Chicago 89
New York 144
Washington 147 
Philadeplhia 73
```

**XML Input**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="class.xsl" type="text/xsl" ?>
<root>
<person><name>John</name>
<property city="Chicago" price="89" />
<property city="New York" price="69" />
<property city="Washington" price="75" /></person>
<person><name>Mike</name>
<property city="New York" price="75" />
<property city="Washington" price="72" />
<property city="Philadeplhia" price="73" /></person>
</root>
```

I thought that I could use generate.id to generate an unique ID for each city and then a `sum()`, but it doesn't work :

```xml
<xsl:value-of select="root/person/property/@city" /> 
<xsl:value-of select="generate-id(.)" />)
```

Comment: This is a *grouping* question. Do a search - it's probably the most often asked XSLT question here. Note that answers are different for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

maybe this helps you to finding the solution (XSLT 2.0):

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="//property" group-by="@city">
     <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/@price)"/>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Comment: I don't know if that's because I'm using XSLT 1.0, but it gives me an empty output.

Comment: @NatachaBK - That's definitely the reason. You should use [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) instead. Example: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxDjimE

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved ! :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="property_by_city" match="property" use="@city"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//property[count(.|key('property_by_city',@city)[1])=1]">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(@city,' ',sum(key('property_by_city',@city)/@price),'&#xA;')"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```